# Are Project|Properties|Build and Build|Set Build Commands really different as the manual says?

Tags: linux, configuration, geany

In Geany, when I navigate to either

- Project|Properties|Build or
- Build|Set Build Commands
  I get the same dialog, even with the same dialog title, and if I modify one or the other they both change.

According to the manual,

> ```
> one for editing user preference settings, activated by the “Set Build Commands” menu item, and
> one for editing project preferences settings, it is the build tab in the Project→Properties dialog and is only available when a project is open.
> ```

Or is there maybe some option that links both?

Comment: What version of Geany are you running? I can't seem to find the excerpts you refer to in [the manual for current version 1.38](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html).

Comment: @DavidYockey https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/configurebuildmenu, I hadn't noticed it says 'Geany version 0.19 and up'. My version is 1.38, but I can imagine this guide could need an update.

Answer (score 0):

When no Project is open, the dialog accessed via the Build menu will contain default settings applicable to whatever files are open at the time. If, however, a Project *is* open, that dialog will reflect whatever is defined in the Project's settings, as indicated in the manual (see https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#project-management).

So, the dialog accessed by the two methods you noted will be identical as long as the dialog is accessible via the Projects menu, which is only possible when a Project is open.